# Handling file permissions in UNIX using awk

Tags: unix, awk, ls

I want to know which permission is given to a file using a shell script. So i used the below code to test for a file. But it shows nothing in output. I just wanted to know where i have made the mistake. Please help me.
The file "1.py" has all read write and execute files enabled.

```
 ls -l 1.py | awk ' {if($1 -eq "-rwxrwxrwx")print 'True'; }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in awk, you shouldn't write shell test, e.g. `[[ ... -eq ...]]`, you should do it in awk way:

`if($1=="whatever")...`

Comment: How do i add an else statement?  ls -l $filemame | awk ' {if($1 == "-rwxrwxrwx")print "True" else print "False"; }'

Comment: @AravindS for your example: `awk '{print ($1=="whatever"?"True":"False")}'` or `awk '{if(.....) print "T"; else print "F"}'`

Comment: If i give your code , it prints recursively for many times continuously

Comment: The output was
1.py
False
False
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False

Comment: @AravindS paste the complete codes you executed. I cannot see why the output could be like that.

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes (`'`) around `True` should be double quotes (`"`), and awk uses `==` for string comparison.

However, depending on what you're trying to do, it might be cleaner to use the Bash builtin tests:

```
if [ -r 1.py -a -x 1.py ]; then
  echo "Yes, we can read (-r) and (-a) execute (-x) the file"
else
  echo "No, we can't."
fi
```

This avoids having to parse ls output. For a longer list of checks, see [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html).

Comment: I also think `-rwxrwxrwx` is a typo, `rwxrwxrwx` was meant here (no leading dash)

Comment: @g-v No, the leading dash has to be there: it indicates type (`-` for files and `d` for directories, and so on)

Answer (score -1):

you could use

```
ls -l 1.py | awk '{if ($1 ==  "-rwxrwxrwx") print "True" }'
```

Comment: @g-v `-eq` is valid in awk, but not for checking if left part and right part are  equal. instead, it does left part `- (minus)` the `eq` variable. if `eq` variable was not assigned before, pick `0 (zero)`

Comment: @Kent There is no -eq in awk though. The fact it doesn't cause a syntax error doesn't change that.

Comment: @123 read my comment again, I didn't say `-eq` is an awk operator

Comment: @Kent g-v's comment is clearly stating that there is no operator though. Your comment appears to be correcting them even though no-one suggested it was invalid syntax.

Comment: @123 , you are right... my comment is kind of confusing... sorry. `-eq ` is not an operator. I explained why the syntax correct. my bad.

Comment: ok so if we are all agreed that the syntax isn't correct please remove the downvote.

Comment: @ClaudioM I didn't downvote, but your answer is not correct. you said `you could use ... or ...`  the first suggestion won't work. It will always return true.

Comment: @Kent I downvoted, the answer is clearly incorrect and i have no idea why someone has upvoted it